Use a Control Value From a Different Form in a Navigation Form
I have a navigation form and I want to use a control from a different form to pass to a control in the clicked on form of the tab.
Me.L3Processes.RowSource = "SELECT L3Process2.ID, L3Process2.L3Process, DataObjects.ID 
FROM DataObjects 
INNER JOIN L3Process2 ON DataObjects.ID = L3Process2.DataObjects.Value 
WHERE DataObjects.ID = '" & [Forms]!L3Process5![DataObjectsList].Column(2) & "'"

I'm on L3Process5 when I click on the tab with the L3Processes list, I want the selected value in L3Process5.DataObjectsList to go into the query above. The query runs in the Form_Open event of the new form.  I get an error that says it can't find the referenced form L3Process5.  Is it because the previous form has already closed?

You are contradicting yourself. You say that you are on L3Process5 and that you want to access a control on another form, but then access [Forms]!L3Process5 again. If this code is in the form L3Process5, then you can access controls on it starting with Me! instead of [Forms]!L3Process5!. Also, if L3Process2 is a table, then what is L3Process2.DataObjects.Value? L3Process2.DataObjects would be a column. In SQL columns do not have a Value property (controls do have, but not table columns).

Multi-Value Fields would have Value property. A Navigation Form loads only one subform at a time. So when you click on L3Processes, L3Process5 is no longer available to reference. Either change to a normal form and a Tab control or use global variable, TempVars, or an unbound textbox on main form to hold value from L3Process5 so it can be used later.

And if DataObjects is MVF, this really compounds the confusion about what you are trying to accomplish.
